# Hide/Blank out a div until checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to finalise design of a product page and basket template for my new site but am having trouble putting all the pieces together.

In the html code below the cart/basket is called using `<div class="ct-cart"></div>` but I need this to either not be visible or blanked out in some way so that a customer has to have ticked the checkbox to agree with the terms and conditions before they can interact with the cart/basket.

I've tried a few scripts I've found online to try and hide it but have been unable to get it to work, even after (hopefully) removing any jQuery conflicts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<p style="text-align:center">
  <input type="checkbox" name="tandc" id="tandc" value="true" class="form-control"><label for="tandc"> Please tick box above to confirm you agree with the <a href="terms.html" title="View terms and conditions of use">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.</label>
</p>
<div class="ct-cart"></div>
```

Comment: You want to show the `.ct-cart` only when the `#tandc` check-box is ticked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure JS implementation. (in case you dont really need jquery)

```js
document.getElementById('tandc').onchange = function(){
  var cart = document.getElementsByClassName('ct-cart')[0];
  if (this.checked) cart.classList.remove('hide');
  else cart.classList.add('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center">
  <input type="checkbox" name="tandc" id="tandc" value="true" class="form-control"><label for="tandc"> Please tick box above to confirm you agree with the <a href="terms.html" title="View terms and conditions of use">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.</label>
</p>
<div class="ct-cart hide">Shown only if checked :)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
(Change event on checkbox triggers visibility class on cart div)

```js
$('#tandc').on('change', function(){
  if ($(this)[0].checked) {
    $('.ct-cart').addClass('ct-cart-visible');
  } else {
    $('.ct-cart-visible').removeClass('ct-cart-visible');
  }
})
```

```css
/* I would use special classes for showing/hiding, just to give more flexibility on styling, how the cart appears */
.ct-cart {
  display: none;
}

.ct-cart-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="text-align:center">
   <input type="checkbox" name="tandc" id="tandc" value="true"
                                               class="form-control"><label for="tandc"> Please tick box above to confirm you agree with the <a href="terms.html" title="View terms and conditions of use">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.</label>
</p>
                                <div class="ct-cart">CART CONTENTS</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the checkbox `change`s you need to run a function.

`if` the checkbox `is` `:checked`, `show()` the `.ct-cart`. Otherwise `hide` the cart.

```js
$('#tandc').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $(".ct-cart").show();
  }else{
    $(".ct-cart").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="text-align:center">
  <input type="checkbox" name="tandc" id="tandc" value="true" class="form-control"><label for="tandc"> Please tick box above to confirm you agree with the <a href="terms.html" title="View terms and conditions of use">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.</label>
</p>
<div class="ct-cart" style="display:none;">
  Cart
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One further approach:

```
function toggle() {

  // convert the NodeList returned by document.querySelectorAll()
  // into an Array, using Array.from():
  Array.from(

    // using document.querySelectorAll() to find the elements that
    // match the selector returned from changed-element's
    // custom data-toggle attribute:
    document.querySelectorAll(this.dataset.toggle)

  // iterating over the Array of nodes:
  ).forEach(

    // using an Arrow function - which avoids changing the
    // 'this' - to toggle the class of 'hidden' depending
    // on whether the changed-checbox is currently checked
    // or not (applying the class-name if the evaluation is
    // true, removing it if false):
    el => el.classList.toggle('hidden', !this.checked)
  );
}

// creating a custom Event (albeit in this case it's the
// browser's 'change' event):
let changeEvent = new Event('change'),

// caching a reference to the relevant element upon which
// the function should fire:
    check = document.getElementById('tandc');


// binding the toggle() function (note the deliberate lack of
// parentheses) as the event-handler for the 'change' event:
check.addEventListener('change', toggle);

// firing the 'change' event on page load,
// in order that the relevant element will be
// shown or hidden appropriately:
check.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

```js
function toggle() {
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(this.dataset.toggle)
  ).forEach(
    el => el.classList.toggle('hidden', !this.checked)
  );
}

let changeEvent = new Event('change'),
  check = document.getElementById('tandc');



check.addEventListener('change', toggle);
check.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

```css
.ct-cart {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center">
  <input type="checkbox" name="tandc" id="tandc" value="true" class="form-control" data-toggle=".ct-cart" /><label for="tandc"> Please tick box above to confirm you agree with the <a href="terms.html" title="View terms and conditions of use">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.</label>
</p>
<div class="ct-cart">Cart content</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).